# Job oracle se ejecuta solo

Tags: oracle

Tengo este job:

```
DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(RT_job,'pkg_rt_semaforo.prc_rt_semaforo;',sysdate+0.00034722);
commit;
```

El `sysdate + 30 segundos` funciona bien, no le estoy parametrizando `INTERVALO`, pero al parecer el job se esta ejecutando una y otra vez.

Debe haber entonces por defecto un Intervalo?

O que debería parametrizarle, para que no se vuelva a ejecutar?

Comment: _al parecer_ no es una gran prueba de que se esté ejecutando. Qué te devuelve esta consulta: `select job,last_date,next_date,broken from dba_jobs where job=XX` (donde XX es el No. de Job que te devolvió al registrarlo) ??

Comment: Debería funcionar correctamente tal cual. Además de lo que te pidió @jachguate, puedes también incluir la columna `interval`?  `select ... interval ... from dba_jobs ...`

Comment: Pero no tengo acceso a DBA_JOBS. Gracias, seguire indagando.